# I need to make a shell script that displays config files without the commented and empty lines

Tags: command-line, scripts, sed

This is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Type in your file"
read file
sed -r -e 's/(^[^#]*$) ; s/(^[^;]*$) ; s/(^[^$]*$) ; s/(^[^/]*$) ; s/(^[^ ]*$)' $file
```

This is the output when I give it a file:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 31: unknown option to `s'

Why am I getting this error? **Would you suggest another way to do it?**
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Each substitute expression needs a PATTERN **and** a REPLACEMENT, like `s/SOMETHING/OTHER/`; your `s/(^[^#]*$) ; s/(^[^;]*$)` tries to replace `(^[^#]*$) ; s` with `(^[^;]*$) ; s` using `(^[^$]*$)` as an "unknown" option

Answer (score 0):

This might help more:

```
grep -Ev '^\s+$|^#' file.txt
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for replaying. I don't think I really understand how this command works. How is it different from just `grep -v '^#' $file`?

Answer (score 0):

Should remove most comments and empty lines:

```
pcre2grep -v '^[[:blank:]]*([#;]|//|$)' file
```